# Prove this isn't a Hilbert space?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

Let $D=(-1,1),$ $f(x)=1-1|x|,$

$g(x)=-\text{sgn}(x)$, $V=\{v \in C^{1}[-1,1]\mid v(1)=v(-1)=0\}.$

Prove there exists a sequence $v_{n} \in V$ such that $v_{n} \rightarrow f$ and $v'_{n} \rightarrow g$ in $L^2(D)$.

Prove that V isn't a Hilbert space w.r.t. the inner product $(u,v)_{1}= \int (uv + u'v') dx$.

I've found a sequence satisfying these conditions is

\begin{equation*}
v_{k}(x)=
\begin{cases}
  1-|x| \;\; \text{for }  x \leq \frac{-1}{k}\\      
  -\frac{k}{2}x^2 + 1-\frac{1}{2k} \;\; \text{for } \frac{-1}{k} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{k} \\
  1-|x| \;\;  \text{for }  x \geq \frac{1}{k}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Now to prove the 2nd part of the question I need to show that $v_{k}$ is a Cauchy sequence in order to show that $V$ isn't complete and therefore not a Hilbert space.
How can I do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Well one way would be to directly evaluate $\| v_i - v_j \|_V $ and prove that $\| v_i - v_j \|_V\to0$ as $i,j\to\infty$ - this would involve splitting$(0,1)$ into several cases and evaluating/estimating the corresponding integral

Comment: However, I don't see why you can't just use that $\|v_i-v_j\|_{L^2(D)} \leqslant \|v_i -f \|_{L^2(D)}+\|v_j -f \|_{L^2(D)} \to 0$ as $i,j\to \infty$ and $\|v_i'-v_j'\|_{L^2(D)} \leqslant \|v_i' -g \|_{L^2(D)}+\|v_j' -g \|_{L^2(D)} \to 0$ then write $\|v_i-v_j\|_V = \sqrt{\|v_i-v_j\|_{L^2(D)}+\|v_i'-v_j'\|_{L^2(D)}}  $.